# SAP HANA change / disable auto-logout on Web based development workbench

Tags: sap-hana

How to **disable auto-logout** for/on: 
 Produkt: SAP HANA 
 Tool: SAP HANA **Web based development workbench**?

When working with HANA Studio you can continue working after a long pause e.g. Lunch - without the need to re-login.

On the "Web based development workbench" however you get logged out even after a short time e.g. coffee break. How to stop auto-logout?

Comment: Are you the administrator, or just a user of the system? I'm guessing that if the option exists, it will be available to the admin to set.

Comment: I think so too. I logged in as SYSTEM user.

Comment: Really unclear? What is not understood? I think everybody working on Hana Web ... knows what I mean

Comment: I further specified. So I think it should even clear what I mean if you are not an SAP HANA expert ;)

Comment: If this is specifically for a web application, then it is off-topic for SuperUser. There is a Web Applications StackExchange site that is set up specifically to answer questions about web sites that behave like programs.

Comment: @music2myear Thx for the info. How to migrate the question ?

Answer (score 1):

It is the parameter in:

Administration > Configuration > xsengine.ini > httpserver > sessiontimeout

[image: Administration Icon / Setting]

[image: sessiontimeout parameter]

Comment: yes you are right - but I needed time to validate.. removed I think ...